# How would you generate multiple scatterplot in Flexdashboard R

Tags: r, ggplot2, flexdashboard

I have a reactive input, which takes values from 1 to 12, what I want to achieve is a plot using one column as the x variable (always), and different columns as the y variable - The input below works fine, but obviously is hardcoded, so if I use less or more than 6 variables the plot doesn't work

```r
ggplotly(
  ggplot(table_plot(),aes(x=Streamer_Offset)) +
    geom_point(aes(y= CMP_1, color = "Source 1"))+
    geom_point(aes(y= CMP_2, color = "Source 2"))+
    geom_point(aes(y= CMP_3, color = "Source 3"))+
    geom_point(aes(y= CMP_4, color = "Source 4"))+
    geom_point(aes(y= CMP_5, color = "Source 5"))+
    geom_point(aes(y= CMP_6, color = "Source 6"))
  
)
```

What I want to do is to put a vector of variables for example c(CMP_1,CMP_2....) etcetera, I have tried to use the following code to create a vector, and then pass on to a formula, but ggplot doesn't recognize the input

```
  l <- colnames(table_plot())
  m <- c(paste0("~",l))
  d <- m[1:length(m)-1]
  as.formula(d)
```

Additionaly I tried ggloop and renderPlot or renderPLotly won't work with that function, as such, I'm not sure what to do as in principle, this should not be a very complicated process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you get the data in long format. Try this -

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplotly(
    ggplot(table_plot() %>% pivot_longer(cols = -Streamer_Offset),
           aes(x=Streamer_Offset, y = value, color = name))
)
```